# How to scrape the search suggestion using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the search suggestion from the [Crunchbase](https://www.crunchbase.com/).
I find the search box and send the words to the website but I want to scrape the search suggestion result without send **ENTER** key but When i type manually I'm getting the search suggestion but through selenium I'm not getting search suggestions.

Here is What I've done so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
d = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
books = ['netflix']
for book in books:
  d.get('https://www.crunchbase.com/home')
  e = d.find_element_by_id('mat-input-0')
  e.send_keys(book)
  sleep(5)
```

**You can see here there is no search suggestions when using Selenium**
[image]

**You can see the search suggestion when manually type**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this element need to be clicked to show this page,like the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
d = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
books = ['netflix']
for book in books:
  d.get('https://www.crunchbase.com/home')
  e = d.find_element_by_id('mat-input-0')
  e.click()
  e.send_keys(book)
  sleep(5)
```

[image]